# How do I fetch all headers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, response-headers

Quick and dirty experiment:

```js
function fetchHead(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders())
        }
    }

    request.open('HEAD', url, true)
    request.send(null)
}
```

It only shows three headers: `["cache-control", "content-type", "expires"]`. But there are a dozen headers in the actual response, as seen in the Network Inspector in the Development Toolbar.

Is there any (other) way to get all headers in Javascript? Is it possible (at all) to read a custom response header from within Javascript?

PS - The response does have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Somehow the browsers does seem to strip out a lot of the headers though.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @klanmiko Google Chrome 83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons browsers restrict access to most HTTP Headers calls via XMLHttpRequest. Best reference for this is probably the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#headers-class).

These restricted list can be expanded by the server returning a [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) header telling the browser which headers are safe for JavaScript to have access to.

Comment: So basically there is no way around it without using a proxy. That's anti-climactic, but clear.

Comment: Correct. Or otherwise you could ask for access to `set-cookie` headers for example and therefore get access to cookies your domain shouldn’t see. Just one example of the dangers of unrestricted access.

Comment: And thanks for the correction. You are correct - been a while since I looked at this!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. [MDN](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders%20the%20headers%20will%20be%20returned%20in%20lowercase.) says that all headers will be returned in lowercase.